# Can the limma package be applied to Log2 RUV-normalized data?

Tags: r, batch-normalization

So I have a dataset that consists of the batch correction through RUV-normalization of several microarray datasets containing tumoral and non-tumoral samples. The data is in Log2 RUV-normalized expression. I want to perform differential expression analysis. Is the limma package in R fit for this? From what I've read the limma package expects Log2 expression data without normalization, but some tutorials I also find use normalized data.

Thank you very much to all!

Comment: This question is too software-specific to be on-topic on this Cross Validated site. The [Bioconductor Forum](https://support.bioconductor.org/) would be a better source of help.

Comment: oh, I am sorry. Thank you for the warning!